# Erlang: How do you send yourself a handle_info message?

Tags: erlang

Other than timer:send_after/2, is there a way to send a gen_server a `handle_info` message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Every message to a gen_server process other than a call, cast or sys message will be handled by the `handle_info` function, so just `GenServerPid ! Msg`. If you're sending the message to the same process, `self() ! Msg`.